# Typescript error while using angular typed forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface ILoginDto {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

And the following component (only relevant code):

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class LoginComponent {

  form = this.getLoginForm();

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  private getLoginForm(): FormGroup<ILoginDto> {
    return this.fb.nonNullable.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error from Typescript:

```
error TS2344: Type 'ILoginDto' does not satisfy the constraint '{ email: AbstractControl<any, any>; password: AbstractControl<any, any>; }'.
  Types of property 'email' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

18   private getLoginForm(): FormGroup<ILoginDto> {
                                       ~~~~~~~~~
```

And this one as well:

```
error TS2322: Type 'FormGroup<{ email: FormControl<string>; password: FormControl<string>; }>' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<ILoginDto>'.
  Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
    Type '{ email: FormControl<string>; password: FormControl<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'ILoginDto'.

19     return this.fb.nonNullable.group({
       ~~~~~~
```

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#optional-controls-and-dynamic-groups), it shouldn't throw such errors and expect simple interfaces without them having to declare any type related to controls.

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiAQgV2AGwCYCmUANCmgOJQSZikBqAhjsHgzNAM5wC+cAZlRBwA5AAEGAOwDmmHAygB6Pmg7CA3ACgNBAB6RYcYBJhE+DAMYE4ASQAyEKUYAi7RBrhwCIBrgBccDhgoIylNDzAGDg4Ad2g8f0Dg6U1uLV19eHM5KLh7RwkAYQhwCAkCYzd3fjQ4AF44GAALYA4AOikCGDyjVCgQAAoASk0q81LEzHN2KH6wYIA3NisoAgY8UpwAT34AI39ejGx8IkG3D1SqueBFkzgOrocetCH9iioaAB47R4kXCAA+M4eOArGCYKASBrNNp8HatCSlABysjkOxwBHa7zA-QQVWBnm8fjgAG1hMJSMTGMxWNM2l4fDh6EwWGxOK0VgBHbArPAAXV5xDxwIiUViUHiJLJFKpLNp7IIXOAPP5gvx3GGVVSqSAA) to the reproduce the problem.

Comment: In which part of docs it say: _without them having to declre any type related to controls_

Comment: @JRichardsz you are absolutly right - I don't know how I missed it. Is there any way to avoid creating it? I would expect that there would be an option to provide a simple interface which represents the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're providing the wrong type since the form is made up of formcontrols

```
export interface ILoginForm {
  email: FormControl<string>;
  password: FormControl<string>;
}
```

```
private getLoginForm(): FormGroup<ILoginForm>
```

Keeping `ILoginDto` can be done via a mapped type:

```
type AsFormGroup<T> = FormGroup<{
 [K as keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>
}>

type ILoginForm = AsFormGroup<ILoginDto>
```

Comment: So it is pretty usless. I need to create new interface for the forms. Is there any way to use the plain dto?

Comment: Yea, just created such myself. Anyidea why there is no such type provided by the angular core package?

Comment: @vlio20 it gets complicated with FormArrays etc

Comment: The Angular team was so excited about introducing typed forms, but they missed on adding at least 2 utility types to map an interface to AbstractControls and the other way around. That's why so many users have problems. And when you start using form arrays, it's just a plain Dx nightmare. Congrats.